# Use matplotlib quiver function with SymPy symbolic expressions

Tags: matplotlib, sympy

```
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

V0 = 1
L = 1

x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
v = -V0*y/(cosh(x/L)*cosh(x/L))
dv = diff(v,y)
u = -integrate(dv,x)

print(dv)
print(u)

plt.figure()
x = np.arange(0,5,1)
y = np.arange(0,5,1)

plt.quiver(x,y,u,v)
```

This part cannot plot, the error is

> ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing symbolic and numeric. `quiver` needs numeric inputs, you can't give it symbolic expressions `u` and `v`. Also, you are redefining x, y to be arrays after they were symbols -- this is not "assigning values to symbols", it's just a confusing instance of variable reuse. Don't do that. After you have found symbolic expressions u and v, do this (note that x, y keep their original meaning as SymPy symbols):

```
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import ufuncify
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,5,1), np.arange(0,5,1))
uxy = ufuncify((x, y), u)
vxy = ufuncify((x, y), v)
plt.figure()
plt.quiver(X, Y, uxy(X, Y), vxy(X, Y))
```

Here, [ufuncify](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html#ufuncify) generates binary functions (uxy, vxy) that support broadcasting on numpy arrays. This makes it possible to plug in X, Y arrays and get an array of values. Then plotting works as expected.

[image: quiver plot]